# submit button works as intended on http but not on https in asp.net 1.1

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I am trying to build a form in asp.net 1.1, the problem I am facing is when I run the page on http everything works fine, but on https  it submits the page with out any validation on client side. The page supposed to validate fields which it does on http but not https.

Page works in all other browsers. FF,chrome,safari,ie6, ie7, the problem is only in IE8 and only when the page moves to https.

Using windows server 2003 on IIS v6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using JavaScript to do client-side validation? If so, are you including the script from a URL that is SSL or non-SSL? If the script isn't going over SSL, perhaps IE is throwing it out as insecure.

Comment: I had a problem with java script files witch weren't being read on secure channel, what I did is downloaded those files and saved it locally. Props for the answer.